# Assign multiple ui-block to element jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to assign multiple ui-blocks to one element?

I want to use a five-column layout with 4 being assigned to one input and the spare to an image. I have tried just adding multiple ui-blocks to one element but no joy.

```
  <fieldset class="ui-grid-d">
      <div class="ui-block-a ui-block-b ui-block-c ui-block-d ">
     <input type="text"  id="item" placeholder="Error/Part number">
      </div>
      <div class="ui-block-e">
        <img src="img/scan_button.png" alt="scan button">
      </div>
  </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.

What you can do is use a 2-column layout with custom width setting (not 50/50):

**CSS**:

```
.width-80 { width: 80% !important; }
.width-20 { width: 20% !important; }
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a width-80">
        <input type="text" id="item" placeholder="Error/Part number">
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b width-20">
        <img src="img/scan_button.png" alt="scan button">
    </div>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uXLF4/)**